# Finding data statistics using mahout

Tags: mahout

I am new to mahout and i am trying to find how i can make use of my dataset to present some relations. I have a dataset of the sort

```
IPs,timestamp,bytes_tranferred
```

what are the different relationships i can derive from this set so that i can present some meaningful values using mahout. Currently am planning to use this set to represent which client (in IPs column) had more traffic for a given time. So i will have to group IPs together i guess. Are there any better ideas and how can i do it using JAVA code. Kindly suggest.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Basically it depends your requirement.you can calculate data transfer in a time duration,ip having data transfer during a time duration etc.but to calculate dont think you need mahout framework,simple MR job can do all these.

Comment: So thats what i need suggestion from you experts that if i have to use mahout then what are the usecases that i can create using which i can provide some statistics of these fields to users using mahout.